# Error when using find/find_one pymongo methods when on an apache2 server (mongodb atlas)

Tags: mongodb, apache, flask, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

when using find/find_one pymongo methods when on an apache2 server i get the following error :

```
No <class 'cryptography.x509.extensions.TLSFeature'> extension was found
```

when using pymongo on an apache2 server to connect and insert or delete in my mongodb collections it works just fine, but when i try to pull something out of the database (using find or find_one methods) i get an error, please note that this error only occurs while running the apache2 server, because when i connected and used find methods in a locally run python script it gave me the information without any errors.

if it is of any relevance, the web framework i am using is flask.

Edit : As for what is producing the error i dont know for sure, so here are the logs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/var/www/html/srv21/SRVApp.py", line 17, in downloadpage
    ThreadID = ThreadID.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1248, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1165, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1052, in __send_message
    response = client._run_operation(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/_csot.py", line 105, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1330, in _run_operation
    return self._retryable_read(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/_csot.py", line 105, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1442, in _retryable_read
    with self._socket_from_server(read_pref, server, session) as (sock_info, read_pref):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1282, in _socket_from_server
    with self._get_socket(server, session) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1217, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(handler=err_handler) as sock_info:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1407, in get_socket
    sock_info = self._get_socket(handler=handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1520, in _get_socket
    sock_info = self.connect(handler=handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1358, in connect
    sock = _configured_socket(self.address, self.opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 1061, in _configured_socket
    sock = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=host)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/pyopenssl_context.py", line 369, in wrap_socket
    ssl_conn.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/pyopenssl_context.py", line 125, in do_handshake
    return self._call(super(_sslConn, self).do_handshake, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/pyopenssl_context.py", line 108, in _call
    return call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1894, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1603, in _raise_ssl_error
    self._context._ocsp_helper.raise_if_problem()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 319, in raise_if_problem
    raise self._problems.pop(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 539, in wrapper
    valid = callback(conn, ocsp_data, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/ocsp_support.py", line 298, in _ocsp_callback
    ext = _get_extension(cert, _TLSFeature)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pymongo/ocsp_support.py", line 114, in _get_extension
    return cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(klass)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 135, in get_extension_for_class
    raise ExtensionNotFound(
cryptography.x509.extensions.ExtensionNotFound: No <class 'cryptography.x509.extensions.TLSFeature'> extension was found
```

Comment: What is generating the error? ...`pymongo`? ... `flask`?  ...`apache`? Do you use the same `pymongo` `client` for all operations, or do you create a new `client` for each operation? Does `pymongo`'s `aggregate` work normally?  Would you show the relevant code?

Comment: @rickhg12hs i dont know what exactly is generating the error but i will edit the post and post logs if that would help, i use 2 clients (the first for the main site '/' and the other for a subdomain) that get created at the start of the file so they get created only once. and aggregate gives the same error as find and find_one does.

Comment: Looks like `pymongo` is trying to use OCSP. Do you have [`PyOpenSSL`, `requests` and `service_identity`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) installed?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes, and the version of them are all relatively recent.

Comment: Do you have a recent install of the python package `cryptography`?  The `TLSFeature` extension has been in there for years.

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes it is the 3.2 version and i looked up when the tlsfeature was added and it was i believe 2.9, tbh i think its something that has to do with apache because when i do the find function on the python interpreter it returns the document just fine without any errors. if there is any problem that you may know of where apache or wsgi messes with packages please tell me.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with apache/wsgi.  It seems unlikely the packages would be messed with, but weirder things have happened.  Are the certs available to `pymongo`/`cryptography`?